# CISCO 2500 IPC streaming in Windows Phone 8

Tags: video-streaming, windows-phone-8, cisco, ip-camera, http-streaming

I am developing a WP8 app, which needs to implement the real-time video streaming feature. Thus far, I have followed [these steps](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Windows%20Phone%208%20Player%20Documentation&referringTitle=Documentation), to configure the Silverlight video player in my app. I have [Cisco 2500](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps6918/ps9692/ps7307/data_sheet_c78-455613.html) (wired) and Cisco Switch. I am able to get the ASF stream via HTTP, using the following URL:

```
http://<username>@<password>.<ip-address>/img/video.asf
```

which works fine with Windows Media Player, VLC player and IE10 on Windows 8 OS.

When I tried to open the same URL in Windows Phone 8's IE (and `MediaPlayer` elements's `Source` attribute in my app), it gives me an error; "Your phone doesn't support this video format".

In Media Information, VLC suggests that its using MP4S codec to stream the video.

Can anyone please suggest how to deliver simple live cast on Windows Phone -- without involving IIS (yet smooth streaming) -- in the aforementioned setup?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ASF formats aren't part of the [supported media codecs for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). If your ASF is just a big clumsy wrapper to a standard audio/video progressive download you can get the ASF, unpack it and use the real media endpoint with Windows Phone.

If you're doing video adaptive streaming to windows phone it might be best if you consider using [IIS Smooth Streaming Media Service](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming)s alongside with [SmoothStreamingMediaElement](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29940)/[SmfPlayer](http://smf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Since IIS SmoothStreaming is not an option, can you please elaborate (or provide sample), how to handle the progressive steam? The camera provides ASF stream over HTTP, JPEG over HTTP and SAV over RTSP. Thanks.